# Display ion-avatar on top of ion-header

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

Is it possible to bring items in `ion-content` in front of the toolbar/header?
I want to center the avatar between the toolbar and the rest of the page.

PS: I don't want to apply the background photo to the `ion-content` instead of the toolbar, because I don't have the full photo.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5q2.png)

```
<ion-header no-border>


 <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-back" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title color="secondary">title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen="true" slot="fixed">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="headerContent">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="../../assets/girl.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

**and the scss**

```
ion-toolbar {
--background: url('../../assets/background.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
min-height: 226px;
position: absolute;
z-index:100;
}
ion-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

ion-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "FuturaBT";
}

ion-back-button {
  --icon-margin-start: 10px;
  --min-height: 14px;
  --min-width: 17px;
  --icon-font-weight: 0.5px;
}

.card {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:-1;

.headerContent {
    height: 200px;

    .avatar {
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;

        img {
            display: block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: calc(-1*(80px + 4px));
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks